# Не могу запустить OpenServer

Tags: php, openserver

OpenServer не запускается, пару минут назад работал, а сейчас нет. Вот лог Файл C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts недоступен для записи. Питался изменить права доступа но и это не помогло. Win 7, нет антивируса.

Answer (score 1):

Все разобрался, после отключения от wi-fi он снова запустился